# ModulenotFoundError No module named 'mlflow.azureml'

Tags: databricks, mlflow

I am trying to deploy latest mlflow registry model to azure ml in databricks by following this article

https://www.databricks.com/notebooks/mlops/deploy_azure_ml_model_.html

But getting an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlflow.azureml' at the import step.

Running a notebook in Databricks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know which version you are using but [mlflow.azureml](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/1.20.2/python_api/mlflow.azureml.html#module-mlflow.azureml) seems deprecated since 1.19. It is recommended to use https://aka.ms/aml-mlflow-deploy instead.